# Swift incorrect closure in function declaration

Tags: ios, swift, moya

I am trying to use [Moya Networking](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/Readme.md) in my project. I am using this [example](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/Examples/Multi-Target/ViewController.swift). The example is making moya request to connect to server in view controller on Line 56 which is below and using callback methods in Line 72 and Line 78

```
func uploadGiphy() {
    provider.request(MultiTarget(Giphy.upload(gif: Giphy.animatedBirdData)),
                     callbackQueue: DispatchQueue.main,
                     progress: progressClosure,
                     completion: progressCompletionClosure)
}
```

I want to write this function in **NetworkHelper.swift** instead of my view controller but, use its two callback methods (Line 72 and Line 78) in my view controller.

So I wrote the function in **NetworkHelper**:

```
static func getUsers(amount:Int=2, 
gender:Gender = .Male, 
success successCallback: @escaping ([UserModelMain]) -> Void, 
error errorCallback: @escaping (Swift.Error) -> Void, 
failure failureCallback: @escaping (Moya.MoyaError) -> Void, 
progress progressClosure: @escaping (Moya.ProgressResponse) -> Void,
progressCompletion progressCompletionClosure:  @escaping (Moya.Completion) -> Void) 
{

     provider.request(.getUsers(amount: amount, gender: gender),
                         callbackQueue: DispatchQueue.main,
                         progress: progressClosure,
                         completion: progressCompletionClosure)
}
```

Its showing error:

> Cannot convert value of type '((Result) -> Void)
>   -> Void' to expected argument type 'Completion' (aka '(Result) -> ()')

I think I am writing my function **getUsers** wrong. I messed it up. I am weak at  closures.

Kindly help.

**Source Code of request function from Moya networking library**:

```
/// Designated request-making method. 
Returns a `Cancellable` token to cancel the request later.
@discardableResult
open func request(_ target: Target,
                  callbackQueue: DispatchQueue? = .none,
                  progress: ProgressBlock? = .none,
                  completion: @escaping Completion) -> Cancellable {

let callbackQueue = callbackQueue ?? self.callbackQueue
return requestNormal(target, callbackQueue: callbackQueue, progress: progress, completion: completion)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Moya.Completion` is already a completion block. You just need to pass `Moya.Completion` as an argument, instead of `(Moya.Completion) -> Void`.

```
progressCompletion progressCompletionClosure: @escaping Moya.Completion)
```

Your current code, like the error suggest, is sending `((Result) -> Void) -> Void`

Comment: How to make this optional?

Comment: Also, my progress progressClosure: @escaping (Moya.ProgressResponse)  always throws 0.0

Comment: SheikhAtif, Remove @escaping keyword and add "?" to make it optional (Optional closures are default escaping do don't need to use @escaping).

Like below :
progressCompletion progressCompletionClosure: Moya.Completion?)